# Error while passing an array of IDs of Items to be deleted to the backend using Axios.delete()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to delete several Items from a database(mongoose) at once by selecting them and clicking a delete button. I have managed to get from the the database the IDs of each element in the list. I am collecting the IDs of the selected items in the list and storing them in an array called `isCHecked` but the problem is when I click to delete them at once, I get a `AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'` error. I feel the Id is not effectively passed to the backend, please where am I getting it wrong?

here is just the code snippets. Thank you

```
const StockItems = () => {
    const [stockItemsList, setStockItemsList] = useState([])
    const [showCheckBox, setShowCheckBox] = useState(false)
    const [isCHecked, setIsChecked] = useState([])

    const handlecheckbox=(e)=>{
        const {value, checked} = e.target
        console.log(value)
        if(checked){
           setIsChecked([...isCHecked, value])
        }else
          setIsChecked(isCHecked.filter((e)=> e!==value))

    }

    const deleteAll = async()=>{
        console.log(isCHecked)
         await Axios.delete('http://localhost:3500/newItems', {isCHecked}).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.status)
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('something went wrong :(', e));
        //setDeleteMessage(response.data.deleteMessage)
    }
}

//controller code (Backend)
const NewItemsData = require('../models/NewItemsData')
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')

const deleteNewItems = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => { 
    const id = req.body
    console.log(id) // this shows undefined in the console

    if(!id) {
       return res.status(400).json({message: 'Items Id is required'})
    }
    const items = await NewItemsData.findById({_id: {$in: id}}).exec()

    if(!items){
       return res.status(400).json({message: 'Items does not exist'})
    }

     await items.deleteMany()
   // const reply = `Username ${result.username} with ID ${result._id} deleted`
    res.json({message: 'Items has been deleted'})
})

module.exports = {
    deleteNewItems,  
}

//Server
app.use('/newItems', require('./routes/newItemsRoutes'))// a line just to show how my route is mounted in the server

//Routes
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const newItemsController = require('../contollers/newItemsController')

router.route('/')
      .get(newItemsController.getAllNewItems)
      .post(newItemsController.createNewItems)
      .patch(newItemsController.updateNewItems)
      .delete(newItemsController.deleteNewItems)
```

Comment: the issue may be how you're sending the id in the delete request - showing just the server code won't allow anyone to help you fix your error

Comment: the front end code is the //stockItems

Comment: Oh, sorry ... wall of code and all that

Comment: the backend code started where I placed the comment //controller code (Backend)

Comment: `console.log(id) // this shows undefined in the console` ... so, `req.body` is empty, what should it be? i think if you want to populate the delete request body, you need to pass in some `{data: ....}` as the second argument - as opposed to `{isCHecked: ...}` which means nothing to anything - not 100% sure on axios parameters since I don't use it any more

Comment: that is where I have a challenge, what should be "data"?

Comment: perhaps the request should include `{data:isCHecked}` rather than `{isCHecked}`? thought that was obvious from my previous comment

Comment: Thank you @jaromanda X I have successfully crossed this part, i.e console.log now shows up the ids passed to the backend, now the error I am recieving is  CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value. while trying to delete, any ideas?

Comment: nope, is `CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value` the whole error? You're sending an Array of id's, (even if it's a single id), does the server expect an array of id's?

Comment: these are the ids choosen that will initiate a delete action

Comment: sure, I understand your code, but does `NewItemsData.findById` expect an ARRAY of id's or a single one?

Comment: I cant really tell, but I guess its neutral state is one ID

Comment: it's your code in `../models/NewItemsData` isn't it? and I have no idea what "neutral state" even refers to - all I know is, your request body will contain a string representation of an Array

Comment: yea. it is my code, and it will , i am just trying to find a way to match each document in the array with the Ids in the array list so as to delete at once

Comment: but it is not expecting an array of ids

Comment: is `id` and Array or a String representation of an Array? I cant' tell if your server parses JSON or not

Comment: ohh ok, id is a string representation, my server parses JSON,

Comment: so id is an Array, not a String, if your server parses JSON ...

Comment: this [ '65658bd4da1570dec90a7e09', '6565456ada1570dec90a7dfa' ] is exactly what is passed to the backend, i.e Object ids of the elements clicked, is their an issue with this in the first place? like i want to find a way to extract these ids and delete contents in the database associated with these ids

Comment: oh, so your frontend is passing a string (which is correct for JSON) but it's odd that it uses single quotes and not double quotes - which is why your backend is getting a string rather than JSON (assuming you actually DO have a JSON bodyparser of course - no evidence that there is)

Comment: i.e. if the string in req.body were `[ "65658bd4da1570dec90a7e09", "6565456ada1570dec90a7dfa" ]` AND the content-type sent in the request were `application/json`  AND you actually have a JSON bodyparser, then `req.body` would be an Array, not a string ... perhaps that's why your code is failing

Answer (score -1):

In your frontend you need to pass the array of IDs correctly in the request body. Instead of `{ isCHecked }`, you should pass an object with a key like `{ ids: isCHecked }`. It's better to use `data` instead of directly sending the object.

```js
const deleteAll = async () => {
    console.log(isCHecked);
    await Axios.delete('http://localhost:3500/newItems', { data: { ids: isCHecked } })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.status);
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('something went wrong :(', e));
};
```

You need to retrieve the IDs in the server correctly from the request body. You are trying to access `req.body`, but you should access `req.body.ids`.

```js
const deleteNewItems = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const ids = req.body.ids; // Change this line
    console.log(ids);

    if (!ids || ids.length === 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Items Id is required' });
    }

    const items = await NewItemsData.findById({ _id: { $in: ids } }).exec();

    if (!items) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Items do not exist' });
    }

    await items.deleteMany();
    res.json({ message: 'Items have been deleted' });
});
```

Comment: still shows the cast error CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{